# How to reduce external disk size - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to reduce external disk size. I have a external disk with 2TB and wanted it to reduce it to 1 TB.

I tried using snapshots and but it does not allows to reduce to 1TB.

My mount -> /dev/sdb

Answer (score 1):

As per google [official Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk) You can only resize a persistent disk to increase its size. You cannot reduce/decrease the size of a persistent disk.

Refer to this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358901/19230181) might be helpful.